# How to drop proxy_table in sybase

Tags: sybase

How to drop a proxy table in sybase ?

I have created like this

```
CREATE PROXY_TABLE tab1 AT 'server.db.dbo.tab1'
```

how to drop it ? I tried like this

```
DROP PROXY_TABLE tab1
```

I Am afraid to apply it like this but is it possible to drop the other table in the second server ?

```
drop table tab1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent the drop table command from being relayed to your remote system, you'll need to turn on trace flag 11211

[From page 68 of the CIS guide](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32702.1600/doc/pdf/ase_cis_users.pdf):

> Traceflag 11211: Prevents the **drop table** syntax from being forwarded to remote servers if the table was created using the **create table at location** syntax.

Comment: Thanks for the answer i used central sybase .. but the weird thing the central used normal drop table i dunno how did that happen